# Returning columns based on various conditions in Group By

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I would like to do a 'group by' on the following example table

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

1. [Low] = Min of [Low] column
2. [High] = Max of [High] column
3. [Symbol]
4. [Epoch]
5. [CuVol]
6. [Dt10Min])
7. [Close]
8. [Open]

Columns 3-7 have the values corresponding to highest Epoch, which is 129 in this case and columns 8 will be the value of [Open] at lowest Epoch of the group [Dt10Min],127 in this case.

I am very new to SQL can you please suggest.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Please add a tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by putting your data into a temp table. For future questions you'll want to do this in the question itself so people that want to help you don't have to copy it by hand from a screenshot. I made some guesses about data types:

```
CREATE TABLE #input (
    Symbol VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Epoch INT NOT NULL,
    [Open] NUMERIC(9, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Close] NUMERIC(9, 1) NOT NULL,
    [High] NUMERIC(9, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Low] NUMERIC(9, 1) NOT NULL,
    CuVol INT NOT NULL,
    Dt10Min DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #input
VALUES
('A', 127, 23.6, 24, 23.9, 22.8, 1600, '20100822')
, ('A', 128, 24.6, 24.1, 24.8, 23.6, 3200, '20100822')
, ('A', 129, 23.7, 24.6, 23.9, 23.5, 4800, '20100822');
```

Now let's write separate queries for all of the information that you want and combine them at the end. Getting the minimum value from a table is very straightforward:

```
SELECT MIN([Low])
FROM #input;
```

As is getting the maximum value from a table:

```
SELECT MAX([High])
FROM #input;
```

Carrying along column values based on the minimum or maximum of another column is more complex. Around here we call that a "greatest n per group" problem. If you just need a single row then you can use the TOP operator. SQL Server will do a TOP 1 sort which will require any extremely low memory grant. This can be helpful if your table is very large. The query below returns the row with the lowest `Epoch`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Open]
FROM #input
ORDER BY Epoch ASC;
```

We can write a very similar query to return data associated with the largest `Epoch`. It's also easy to select as many columns as needed:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Symbol, [Epoch], [CuVol], [Dt10Min], [Close]
FROM #input
ORDER BY Epoch DESC;
```

Now we need to combine all of the queries together to get a single result set. Each query is guaranteed to return a single row, so we might as well use `CROSS JOIN`. Here's the complete query:

```
SELECT
  highest_epoch.symbol
, highest_epoch.Epoch
, lowest_epoch.[Open]
, highest_epoch.[Close]
, min_max.High
, min_max.Low
, highest_epoch.CuVol
, highest_epoch.Dt10Min
FROM
(
    SELECT
      MIN(i.[Low]) [Low]
    , MAX(i.[High]) [High]
    FROM #input i
) min_max
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Symbol, [Epoch], [CuVol], [Dt10Min], [Close]
    FROM #input
    ORDER BY Epoch DESC
) highest_epoch
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Open]
    FROM #input
    ORDER BY Epoch ASC
) lowest_epoch;
```

This query returns the results that you're looking for:

```
╔════════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════╦══════╦══════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ symbol ║ Epoch ║ Open ║ Close ║ High ║ Low  ║ CuVol ║         Dt10Min         ║
╠════════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ A      ║   129 ║ 23.6 ║ 24.6  ║ 24.8 ║ 22.8 ║  4800 ║ 2010-08-22 00:00:00.000 ║
╚════════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════╩══════╩══════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Without any indexes, it'll do three scans of the table but it shouldn't require sorting. That could be okay depending on the size of the table and your response time requirements. However, if you need to speed the query up you could consider adding covering indexes for each derived table or you could use a more advanced technique to do the "greatest n per group" calculations. For example, it's possible to use `GROUP BY` to carry along extra columns as I showed in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183468/use-group-by-and-return-more-than-2-columns/183787#183787).

Comment: Thank you Joe, this solution is great and you wonderfully explained it. However my table has 300million records and SQL Server says out of memory even with 40GB of RAM allocated to it.

Comment: @vkb I posted a better solution which shouldn't require anything more than a trivial memory grant. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'll borrow Joe's `create table/insert` example, and assuming `Symbol` is the effective PK for the final result I've thrown in a second set of data for `Symbol = 'B'`:

```
create table #input
(Symbol   varchar(1)    NOT NULL
,Epoch    int           NOT NULL
,[Open]   numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,[Close]  numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,High     numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,Low      numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,CuVol    int           NOT NULL
,Dt10Min  datetime      NOT NULL
);

insert into #input
values

('A', 127, 23.6, 24,   23.9, 22.8, 1600, '20100822'),
('A', 128, 24.6, 24.1, 24.8, 23.6, 3200, '20100822'),
('A', 129, 23.7, 24.6, 23.9, 23.5, 4800, '20100822'),

('B', 227, 33.6, 34,   33.9, 32.8, 1605, '20100821'),
('B', 228, 34.6, 34.1, 34.8, 33.6, 3205, '20100822'),
('B', 229, 33.7, 34.6, 33.9, 33.5, 4805, '20100823');
```

We'll create a derived table of the `max()/min()` values (grouped by `Symbol`), then use the derived table's `min(Epoch)/max(Epoch)` values to perform 2 joins back to the raw data to generate our final result set:

```
select  dt.Symbol,
        dt.highEpoch  as Epoch,
        lowE.[Open]   as [Open],
        highE.[Close] as [Close],
        dt.maxHigh    as High,
        dt.minLow     as Low,
        highE.CuVol   as CuVol,
        highE.Dt10Min as Dt10Min
from
(select Symbol,
        min(Epoch) as lowEpoch,
        max(Epoch) as highEpoch,
        max(High)  as maxHigh,
        min(Low)   as minLow
from    #input
group by Symbol) dt

join    #input lowE
on      lowE.Symbol  = dt.Symbol
and     lowE.Epoch   = dt.lowEpoch

join    #input highE
on      highE.Symbol = dt.Symbol
and     highE.Epoch  = dt.highEpoch

order by dt.Symbol;

Symbol | Epoch | Open | Close | High | Low  | CuVol | Dt10Min            
------ | ----- | ---- | ----- | ---- | ---- | ----- | -------------------
A      |   129 | 23.6 | 24.6  | 24.8 | 22.8 |  4800 | 22/08/2010 00:00:00
B      |   229 | 33.6 | 34.6  | 34.8 | 32.8 |  4805 | 23/08/2010 00:00:00
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=593b48d48a59b0e12cd83dc0aec2883d) for the above.

Comment: Thanks markp, this definitely helps. With 300million records (26GB disk space) and 40GB allocated to SQL Server, the process was not completed. I think i should process it using python/spark.

Comment: Unless you plan on loading 26GB of data into your python/spark app, you may want to spend some time on checking for tuning opportunities with the proposed query (eg, an index on (Symbol,Epoch) should speed up the joins to the `lowE` and `highE` tables; if you have multiple engines - aka free cpu cycles - run multiple copies of the above against subsets of the main table - aka, parallelize the operation)

Answer (score 1):

Overall, this problem is a `top-n-per-group` problem with a slight twist. You need to find both the first and the last values in each group.

If you use SQL Server 2012 or later, one way to do it is to use `ROW_NUMBER` and `FIRST_VALUE` / `LAST_VALUE` functions.

**Sample data** (thank you @markp)

```
create table #input
(Symbol   varchar(1)    NOT NULL
,Epoch    int           NOT NULL
,[Open]   numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,[Close]  numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,High     numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,Low      numeric(9, 1) NOT NULL
,CuVol    int           NOT NULL
,Dt10Min  datetime      NOT NULL
);

insert into #input values
('A', 127, 23.6, 24,   23.9, 22.8, 1600, '20100822'),
('A', 128, 24.6, 24.1, 24.8, 23.6, 3200, '20100822'),
('A', 129, 23.7, 24.6, 23.9, 23.5, 4800, '20100822'),

('B', 227, 33.6, 34,   33.9, 32.8, 1605, '20100821'),
('B', 228, 34.6, 34.1, 34.8, 33.6, 3205, '20100822'),
('B', 229, 33.7, 34.6, 33.9, 33.5, 4805, '20100823');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Symbol
        ,Epoch
        ,[Open]
        ,[Close]
        ,High
        ,Low
        ,CuVol
        ,Dt10Min
        ,MIN(Low) OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol) AS MinLow
        ,MAX(High) OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol) AS MaxHigh
        ,LAST_VALUE([Open]) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY Epoch DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS FirstOpen
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY Epoch DESC) AS rnDesc
    FROM
        #input
)
SELECT
    Symbol
    ,Epoch
    ,FirstOpen
    ,[Close]
    ,MaxHigh
    ,MinLow
    ,CuVol
    ,Dt10Min
FROM CTE
WHERE rnDesc = 1
;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
| Symbol | Epoch | FirstOpen | Close | MaxHigh | MinLow | CuVol |         Dt10Min         |
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
| A      |   129 | 23.6      | 24.6  | 24.8    | 22.8   |  4800 | 2010-08-22 00:00:00.000 |
| B      |   229 | 33.6      | 34.6  | 34.8    | 32.8   |  4805 | 2010-08-23 00:00:00.000 |
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Without proper indexes the engine would have to sort the table. It could be expensive.

Ideally, create a clustered index, like so:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #input
(
    Symbol ASC
    ,Epoch DESC
);
```

If you already have a clustered index, then add a non-clustered index and `INCLUDE` all other columns into it, like so:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #input
(
    Symbol ASC
    ,Epoch DESC
)
INCLUDE ([Open], [Close], High, Low, CuVol, Dt10Min)
;
```

If including all columns into an index sound like too much, try to add an index just on two columns `(Symbol ASC, Epoch DESC)`, but extra look-ups may be quite expensive.

I used

```
LAST_VALUE([Open]) OVER (... ORDER BY Epoch DESC ...)
```

instead of more intuitive

```
FIRST_VALUE([Open]) OVER (... ORDER BY Epoch ASC ...)
```

to match the index definition. If you use `FIRST_VALUE ... ORDER BY Epoch ASC`, then the engine would do an extra sort even with the index (or two sorts without an index).